# See elements outside of the main form in C# Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm  a little bit frustrated with forms and feel like there have to  be some features that I do not know yet (I'm still new to this). Currently I want to toggle two panels on button click, and have one panel move out on the left while the other moves in on the right. I can get it working somehow, but I'm losing so much time because I can only work on the panel that I see and have to keep dragging the panel that is out of the main form into the main form in order to see it and work on it.

Is there a way to also draw elements that are technically out of the draw range?

The panels should have transparent background and the main form background should not move , so moving in another form does not look like a viable option.

Comment: Have you tried positioning both panels conveniently at design time, then setting the run-time location in the form load event handler?

Comment: I don't know how I could conveniently position both elements at design time so I can edit both of them. The panel fills the entire width and one if being pushed out for the other on button click. Designing both of them at the same time is not really easy given you can either overlap them while designing or move one out of the frame and grab it back later (which has not always worked for me without problems).
Chances are high that I'm just missing something here and overlook the obvious solution to my problem.

Comment: Well alternatively you can make the main form big enough at design time to easily access both panels, then set it to its correct size at runtime.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll have to do something like that. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Is your Form large enough to show both Panel Controls at the same time? Are these Panels on your Form, or on some sub-control?  Who moves these Panels?

Comment: The whole window has 700 width, and its size is fixed. Both panels use that same width. So on button click I move out one panel for the settings panel. It's nothing too crazy and it works now, but I was wondering if there was a more convenient way to work on both panels at the same time. For instance, in Unity you can work on windows that are outside of the canvas. Now I know that Visual Studio is not Unity and does in no way have the same tools and setup, but I was wondering if there was anything remotely similar.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Do you want to see both panels while designing in visual studio, or do you want to see both panels in your program? Do you want to see the panels in your main form, or do you want to see them in separate forms? Do you have any code? If you really want us to help you, edit your question and state your requirements exactly. Don't babble about big deals or not, don't use phrases that can be multi interpreted: "The panel moves to the right". Be precise, be exact in your specification. Don't ask your question in a series of comments, use the edit button